# must it need a full-fill rectangle element in a g(group) element to activate the whole elements within the g element?

Tags: d3.js

when *g* tag is bonded to a mouseover event whether elements within the *g* tag response in concert to the mouseover and don't need another rectangle to fill the g tag?

I am following a d3.js book, it refers to a situation that one visible element (here is a *text* tag) overlaps another (here is a *rectangle*), and if I bind an event (here is *mouseover*) to the deeper element, it won't call the event when your mouse over the upper element (the *text* tag) .

and it gives a solution that you can group the *rect* and *text* tags together, and bind the event to the g element so that both *rect* and *text* could work.

but it also needs a CSS code: *pointer-events: all* and another rectangle to overlap the whole the rectangle and text tags inside the g tag, in this case, it will work.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3: Smoother highlight transitions</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* No style rules here yet */
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Width and height
        var w = 600;
        var h = 250;
        var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
            11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25
        ];

        var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
            .rangeRound([0, w])
            .paddingInner(0.05);

        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
            .range([0, h]);

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

        //Create bars
        svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("g")

            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d);
            })
            .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return yScale(d);
            })
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round(d * 10) + ")";
            });

        //Create labels
        svg.selectAll("g")
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d;
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d) + 14;
            })
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "11px")
            .attr("fill", "white");


        //*****************to add a mouseover event to g tag and overlap the rectangle and text tags above with a rectangle***************************          
        svg.selectAll("g")
            .style("pointer-events", "all")
            .on("mouseover", function() {
                d3.select(this)
                    .select("rect")
                    .attr("fill", "orange");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                d3.select(this)
                    .select("rect")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(250)
                    .attr("fill", "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")");
            })
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d);
            })
            .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return yScale(d);
            })

        //*****************make it invisible*********************************
            .attr("fill", "none");
    </script>
</body>
```

you could copy it into an empty HTML file, and load it, it's a bar chart.

the only question is if a rectangle is needed to fill the unempty g tag to make the bar rectangles and text response together.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52153698/5385381

Comment: you can also set the `pointer-event:none` to the text element, direct or by CSS